# Finding the average speed of an object going down curved slides of different sizes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Say I have a slide that starts at point A which is *h* meters above the ground. The slide ends at point B, which is at ground level and *l* meters from A (horizontally). The length of the slide is *L*. The slide is frictionless, there is no air resistance, and acceleration due to gravity is 9.8 ms$^{-2}$. The shape of the slide is a single, convex curve from A to B.

My question: if I were to experimentally determine the time *t* it takes for an object to slide from A to B from a height *h*, is it possible to use this result to estimate the average speed of the same object going down a different slide where every length is increased by, for example, a factor of five ($5h$, $5l$, $5L$)? The shape of the slide curve doesn't change. When I say average speed, I am referring to:
$$v_{avg}=\frac Lt$$

I wasn't sure where to start with this, so I tried to calculate the average speed for a straight slide.
Using $s=v_{i}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$, I figured that the time taken would be:
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{h}{4.9}}$$
Therefore, average speed would be:
$$v_{avg}=\frac{L}{\sqrt{\frac{h}{4.9}}}=L{\sqrt{\frac{4.9}{h}}}$$
If I then lenghthened each side by a factor of $k$, then:
$$v_{avg}=kL{\sqrt{\frac{4.9}{kh}}}=\sqrt{k}\times{L}{\sqrt{\frac{4.9}{h}}}$$

Using the example from the start, this would mean that the slide where every side is increased by a factor of 5 would have an average speed which is $\sqrt5$ times the average speed that was determined experimentally for the slide of dimensions $h,l, L$. But I am still not sure how this would apply to a curved slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result also applies to general curves.

Let $\ell$ measure the length along the slide from the starting point, and let $h(\ell)$ denote the distance below the starting point. By conservation of energy, the speed at point $\ell$ is
$$ v(\ell) = \sqrt{2gh(\ell)}.$$

The average velocity is
$$v_{avg}=\frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}=\frac{L}{\int\limits_0^Ld\ell/v(\ell)}=\frac{L/\sqrt{2g}}{\int\limits_0^Ld\ell/\sqrt{h(\ell)}}.$$

If the track is scaled up by a factor $\alpha$, we will have $L'=\alpha L$ and $h'(\alpha \ell)=\alpha h(\ell)$, so

$$ v'_{avg} = \frac{L'/\sqrt{2g}}{\int\limits_0^L'd\ell'/\sqrt{h'(\ell')}} = \frac{\alpha L/\sqrt{2g}}{\int\limits_0^{\alpha L}d\ell'/\sqrt{\alpha h(\ell'/\alpha)}}. $$
With the change of variables $\ell=\ell'/\alpha$,
$$ v'_{avg} = \frac{\alpha L/\sqrt{2g}}{\int\limits_0^{L}\alpha d\ell/\sqrt{\alpha h(\ell)}} = \frac{\sqrt\alpha L/\sqrt{2g}}{\int\limits_0^{L}d\ell/\sqrt{h(\ell)}} =\sqrt\alpha v_{avg}.$$